# How can Entity Framework work organically with data push update

Tags: entity-framework, push

I am designing a project. I decide to use EF to model my existing DB tables. Main features are:

1. web users send data queries to web server to retrieve result from tables and display data grid in browser;
2. web server also listens to DB updates (pushed from DB to web server). These data updates are done by external parties. We have to catch these updates and reflect in users browser.

Main question is: Does EF have built-in method to listen to data source in configurable way and trigger update event? Or if not, is there existing good way to let EF and DB updates work together?

Comment: Why does the web server have to listen for updates from DB server? Won't those updates be reflected when the updated data is queried from the DB?

Comment: Do you have a data grid sitting on a page that needs to update when your external updates occur?

Comment: @dudeNumber4 Yes, my data grid wants to get real time updates. The update is driven by a push mechanism in the DB and I can't change that part. I can only listen to the updates and apply to the grid. Do I also need way to apply updates back to EF internal cache?

Comment: @DFord query from DB is pulling. I want real-time push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to main question: no.  I've worked with EF for a long time now; never seen such a feature.

In order to update your data "real time" I would think SignalR would be the solution.  Your client hooks into a SignalR server (declares a handler for a call from the server) and receives the call when something has changed; you refresh your data accordingly (with a new call from EF).  Your SignalR instance does the "catching" of the external party's update and calls the client method telling it to do so.

EF does nothing special in this case.

Comment: OK. In this case, does it make sense to use EF as model framwork? I am new to web dev so this might be silly question.

Comment: You mean use EF as your ORM in general?  I always say yes, but that's just my opinion.  I've used it for very long time; for any faults it has, it's always been a great productivity booster.

Comment: If I use EF, can I implement EF second-level caching and apply received updates to the cached data? Is that a viable solution?

Comment: Viable yes, but Id say this.  I Haven't implemented 2nd level, but: 1) It seems at least as complex as SignalR 2) Beginning with the V6 (essentially) rewrite of EF, we've found it best to get our data with .AsNoTracking & use EF entities fully stateless (caching would seem to be like stateful with yet another layer) 3) Using caching would still require polling, no?  This is the problem SignalR solves.  SignalR would make it truly real-time.